# Understand the dynamic of $z\mapsto az$, with $a\in\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $|a|=1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems

I am trying to determine the set $\omega(z)$ of the possible subsqequences of  the iterated sequence $(f^{\circ n}(z))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, with $f$ being the function described in the title and $z$ a complex number. I write $a=e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, and I consider two cases :

- If $\theta\in2\pi\mathbb{Q}$ : we have that, writing $\theta=2\pi\frac{p}{q}$ with $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $q\in\mathbb{N}^*$, $f^{\circ q}(z)=z$. Thus, as 
  $\omega(z)\subset\overline{\{z,f(z),\dots\}}=\{z,\dots,f^{\circ q-1}(z)\}$, we have that $\omega(z)$ is a finite set.
- If $\theta\notin 2\pi\mathbb{Q}$ : I want to prove that $\omega(z)$ is the circle of center $0$ and of radius $|z|$, $S(0,|z|)$. The subgroup $\theta\mathbb{Z}+2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so $e^{i\theta\mathbb{Z}}$ is dense in $S^1=S(0,1)$. But : I don't know if (and I would to prove that !) $e^{i\theta\mathbb{N}}$ is dense in $S^1$, and how to use efficiently this fact to show that $\omega(z)=S(0,|z|)$ (if I can approximate any point $s\in S^1$ by a sequence $e^{i\theta a_n}$, $a_n\in\mathbb{N}$, how can I be assured that I can approximate $s$ by a sequence $e^{i\theta \tilde{a}_n}$ where $\tilde{a}_n$ is a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers ?).

Note that for the second point, I have tried something which perhaps does not lead to nothing : each of your comments/advice will be helpful. Thank you !

Comment: Everywhere infinite subset of the set of natural numbers contains the image of a strictly increasing sequence.

Comment: In this case I agree with you, but when the set is finite and that $s=e^{i\theta m}$ I have some difficulties to see how to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may proceed as follows for the irrational case: Let $d(x,y)=\min_k|x-y-2k\pi|$ be a metric on ${\Bbb R}/2\pi {\Bbb Z}$. The sequence $x_n=n \theta$ (mod $2\pi$) must accumulate somewhere. So given $\epsilon>0$ there are $m<n$ so that $0<d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$ (equality is not possible by irrationality). But then $0<d(0,x_{n-m})<\epsilon$. Now, the subsequence $x_{k(n-m)}=kx_{n-m}$ mod $2\pi$ will be $\epsilon$ dense in $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: I am trying to understand how to use your argument to conclude : you managed to find a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers (times $\theta$) which is $\epsilon$ dense in $[0,2\pi]$ $(\mod 2\pi)$, and thus to prove that in particular $e^{i\theta \mathbb{N}}=S^1$ (thank you for that proof !). I feel that I loose information in this particular case, and that your argument can help me to find my $\tilde{a}_n$ sequence directly. But I can't see how to extract a such subsequence, because by reducing $\epsilon$ I get new integers $m$ and $n$ and so a new subsequence $x_{k(n-m)}$ ?

Comment: Setting $\Delta=n-m>0$ we may assume that $\delta=x_\Delta\in (0,\epsilon)$ mod $2\pi$. Then the subsequence $x_{k\Delta}= k \delta$ is strictly increasing. Set $N$ to be the smallest integer so that $N\delta>2\pi$. Then $0,\delta,2\delta,...,N\delta$ is $\delta$-dense in $[0,2\pi]$. As everything is mod $2\pi$ it is probably better being a little more careful when 'ordering' the points. But for distances smaller than say $\pi$ there is a natural ordering.

Comment: I agree with that point : what I don't understand is that, if I take a smaller $\epsilon$ (say $\epsilon'$), I get a new $\Delta'$ and a new $\delta'$, s.t. $0,\delta',\dots,N'\delta'$ is $\epsilon'$ dense in $[0,2\pi]$. But doing this, If I want to extract a subsequence which converges to some $\alpha\in[0,2\pi]$, I don't know if the first integer that I choose in the set $\{1,\dots,N\}$ which will give a $\epsilon$ near element to $\alpha$ is smaller than the integer I will choose in the set $\{1,\dots,N'\}$ which will give a $\epsilon'$ near element to $\alpha$ ?

Comment: A non-optimal approach is simply to wait. In other words, suppose you have found $n_k$ so that $d(x_{n_k},\alpha)<1/k$. Now for the next $x_{n_{k+1}}$ you consider only the subsequence $\{x_n: n>n_k\}$. The same proof shows that you may find $x_{n_{k+1}}$  which is $1/(k+1)$ close to $\alpha$ and $n_{k+1}>n_k$ so your sequence will be strictly increasing (if this is what you want). In order to show density you don't really need this.

Comment: Yes it works indeed ! For the density part I agree that it was sufficient, but to study what is my set $\omega(z)$ I have to considerate only strictly increasing subsequences. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I forgot about the $\omega(z)$ story. You are right you need a strictly increasing sequence in that case.